# git: directory seems to be both directory with modification and submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

Some long time ago (in 2011) I had started a project with subdirectories.
At some later time I decided to make those subdirectories submodules actually.

That was so long ago (in 2013) that I don't remember the individual steps.

Now I added two commits to a submodule (doing it in that subdirectory), also tagging a new version, then pushed.

After updating the submodule, adding and committing the changes, in the git main directory `git status` still shows "`modified:` *directory* `(untracked content)`".

I wonder how to get rid of that message (or at least I want to know what is causing that).

Comment: The status message you see means that the *submodule* has status. If you don't want to see submodule status in superproject status, you can suppress it, but usually the thing to do is to go into the submodule and fix it up so that it has no status entities to report in the first place. Then your superproject Git, when it asks the submodule about the status, will get a "nothing to report sir!" response and won't tell you about the submodule.

Comment: In this specific case, "untracked content" means that in the submodule, `git status` is reporting that there untracked files. Treat them the same way you would any untracked file: determine whether the file was supposed to be tracked, or is never supposed to be tracked at all, or is leftover junk that should be removed now, or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer is based on @torek's comments)

> The status message you see means that the submodule has status.

That was the clue: I had diffed some changes into a file in the submodule directory, and that file wasn't ignored by `.gitignore`.
So `git status` inside the submodule said "**Untracked files:**".

Once removing that diff output file in the submodule directory, then the status changed to "**Your branch is up to date** ...".
After changing to the parent directory git status had changed to "**Your branch is up to date** ...", as well.